# How to disable Spring Security login page?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created an application in Spring Boot similar with pastebin.com. It was working good and I added the Spring Security to register and login the users. When I start the project, a login screen is shown when I access http://localhost:8080/ but it's not my login page who supposed to be and I don't know why it appears. Do you know what I should do to fix this issue?

This is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springboot.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-helloworld-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PastebinClone</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the SecurityConfiguration.java class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public abstract class SecurityConfiguration implements SpringSecurityConfig {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .dispatcherTypeMatchers(HttpMethod.valueOf("/registration"))
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

This is RegistrationController.class

```
@Controller
class RegistrationController {

    private final UserRepository userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public RegistrationController(UserRepository userRepo) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public UserRegistrationDTO userRegistrationDTO() {
        return new UserRegistrationDTO();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String showRegistrationForm() {
        return "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("user")
                                          User registrationDTO) {

        userRepo.save(registrationDTO);
        return "redirect:/registration?success";
    }
}
```

Here is the image who appears every time I'm running the code
[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vry3M.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `.formLogin()` configuration in your `SecurityConfiguration` class

Answer (score 0):

As you are using springboot 3.0.0 you can use this code to disable the default login page

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"*/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/login").permitAll();
}
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it's not disabled

Comment: Updated the code can you please try this

Comment: But WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Here you have not made /login url as public. You have to make /login url as public same like /registration.

Also /login url is used to display your login form then you have to create one more url which is used to process your login form. No need to mention that url in controller. You just have to mention that url in your form action.

Mention below code in security configuration

```
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/performlogin")
```

Here, email is name of form field from where you are giving login access and /performlogin url is form action.

If you are using thymeleaf your form looks like this

```
 <form th:action="@{/performlogin}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="email" th:field="*{email}">

            <label >Password:</label>
            <input type="password" th:field="*{password}">

            <input type="submit" value="Login">
      
</form>
```

And mention user object in login controller to bind the data of form

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        return "login";
    }
```

Do changes in form according to your User class.

Comment: I did it, but still I get login page no matter I do!

Comment: Now, are you getting your login page or spring security login page ?

Comment: I still get spring security login page